# Placeholders are not visible on Android

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have the following code

```
<VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="30,10,30,10">
                <Entry Text="{Binding DatoEmpresa.Empresa}" Placeholder="Empresa" Margin="30,5,30,0"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding DatoEmpresa.PersonaContacto}" Placeholder="Persona de Contacto" Margin="30,5,30,0"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding DatoEmpresa.Especialidad}" Placeholder="Especialidad" Margin="30,5,30,0"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding DatoEmpresa.Telefono}" Placeholder="Teléfono" Margin="30,5,30,0" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding DatoEmpresa.Notas}" Placeholder="Observaciones" Margin="30,5,30,0"/>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10"
                    ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
                    <ImageButton x:Name="btnSaveUpdate"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="20"
                            Command="{Binding SaveDatosCommand}"
                            Source="save_file.png"
                            WidthRequest="20"
                            HeightRequest="20"/>
                    <ImageButton x:Name="btnDelete" 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="20"
                            Command="{Binding DeleteDatosCommand}"
                            Source="delete.png"
                            WidthRequest="20"
                            HeightRequest="20"/>
                    <ImageButton x:Name="btnTrabajo" 
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Margin="20"
                            Clicked="btnTrabajo_Clicked"
                            Source="mantenimiento.png"
                            WidthRequest="20"
                            HeightRequest="20"/>
                </Grid>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Running the app in MacCatalyst and in IOS the placeholder for the entries are visible, but running the app in Android they are not visible.
Any idea what I need to do to get them to display?
Thanks

Comment: I've tested it on Android 13 emulator and the placeholder for the entries are all visible, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTmeZ.png), what android device and API version you are running?

Comment: I'm using Pixel 5 emulator and API version 33

Comment: Thanks for the response, your device and api version are the same as mine, can you help provide a sceenshot? Also, if possible, please help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add to your post?

Comment: Hello, preparing the example to send it, I have discovered the problem. The problem was that in the style file I modified the entry as followed        <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="{OnIdiom 40, Phone=20}"/>
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{OnIdiom 40, Phone=20}"/> I have to change Phone= 35. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to set placeholder text color.  **<Entry Placeholder="Write Here!" PlaceholderColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />** Like This.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the value of `MinimumHeightRequest` and `HeightRequest` in of `Entry` in Styles.xaml, changing them to `Phone=35` can resolve the issue.

```
  <Style TargetType="Entry">

     <!--Omitted for brevity>

      <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="{OnIdiom 40, Phone=35}"/>
      <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{OnIdiom 40, Phone=35}"/>
  </Style>
```